# Response to 'Thanking' Speech Acts?

Tags: english, pragmatics

Just wondering if anyone is familiar with any research that touches on this. It seems to be a largely untapped topic, other than [Wooh-yun Jung's (1994) work](http://www.eric.ed.gov/PDFS/ED404879.pdf).

Comment: The tag "corpora" means you're looking for corpora?

Comment: Hi, Eugene! Could add more information about what a "Thanking Speech Act" is and the gist of Wooh-yun Jung's work?

Comment: added a link to the paper

Comment: The tag "english" means you're looking for speech acts in English?

Comment: Untouched? You must be joking! There is so much written on that that it'd take a couple of months to read it. How about part 2 "Responses to thanks: The state of the art"  in Schneider's 2005 paper in "The pragmatics of Irish English", something to start with?

Comment: Guys, can you help edit/suggest the tags? The corpora tag has nothing to do with this , right? Would pragmatics and speech act be appropriate?

Comment: Thanks mark, and yes I'm only interested in English (American) as well as (Responses to Thanks), for example 'You're welcome'. I'll check this stuff out. Sorry for the tag mistake, I'm obviously new to your system here must've clicked it when it popped up.

Comment: @EugeneDanyo No problem Eugene! Don't worry about the tag mistake! :D We asked not to scold you but just to help you, so we could fix any possible mistakes in your question and improve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

University of Minnesota [Center for Advanced Research on Language Acquisition](http://www.carla.umn.edu/speechacts/index.html) maintains a [very complete bibliography on speech acts](http://www.carla.umn.edu/speechacts/bibliography/index.html#menu) in a variety of languages. It's not clear from your question whether you are interested in English only; there is a lot of Japanese work listed as well.

[Here is the page on Thanking acts](http://www.carla.umn.edu/speechacts/bibliography/thanks.html). It includes:

Coulmas, F. (1981).
Eisenstein, M. & Bodman, J. (1995).
Eisenstein, M. & Bodman, J. W. (1986).
Ferrara, K. (1994).
Hinkel, E. (1994).
Ide, R. (1998).
Kim, Y. (1994).
Kimura, K. (1994).
Kumatoridani, T. (1999).
Miyake, K. (1994).
Moriyama, T. (1999).
Nakata, T. (1989).
Ogawa, H. (1995).

So it's certainly a good place to start.